# What ECMAScript implementations extend the RegExp syntax?

Tags: javascript, regex

So I know in JavaScript an implementation is *allowed* to extend the regular expressions grammar:

> An implementation may extend the ECMAScript Regular Expression grammar defined in 21.2.1, but it must not extend the RegularExpressionBody and RegularExpressionFlags productions defined below or the productions used by these productions.

Was this ability ever used? Do any existing JavaScript implementations extend the regular expressions grammar?

Comment: `Looking for concrete examples of current extensions` What else do you want to know on top of whatever already mentioned in the existing answers?

Comment: @nhahtdh what I'm asking: Whether implementations actually take advantage of this feature and how (current answers speak of old versions doing this). What I want to know: If we can safely drop this allowance from the ECMAScript specification now that we have subclassable RegExp.

Comment: I think you might want to clarify that with an edit to your question. Also I'm not sure what you are asking when you say `If we can safely drop this allowance from the ECMAScript specification now that we have subclassable RegExp.` The clause allows for browser implementation to extend the grammar of RegExp (not just by script) and limits such implementation so that it won't cause a confusion with comment syntax, so I guess it should not be dropped.

Comment: @nhahtdh Yes, I realize that browsers currently can do this, but if non _actually_ do this we can drop this allowance in a future version of the ECMASCript spec which would make our lives a lot easier :D

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### Octal escape sequence in RegExp

A wide application of that clause (which also presents in ECMAScript 5.1 specification Section 7.8.5) is to provide octal escape sequence to RegExp constructor.

```
/a\1b/.test("a\u0001b");
/a\11b/.test("a\tb");
```

The default grammar of RegExp (as described in [Section 15.10.1 of ES5.1](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/index.html#sec-15.10.1), or [Section 21.2.1 of ES6](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/index.html#sec-patterns)) doesn't support octal escape sequence, and any decimal escape sequence whose value larger than the number of capturing groups triggers **SyntaxError**. However, many browsers (even old versions) extends the RegExp grammar to support octal escape sequence and evaluates the 2 lines of code above to `true`.

Starting from ES6, [Annex B](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/index.html#sec-additional-ecmascript-features-for-web-browsers), which used to be an *informative* annex in ES3 to ES5.1 specs, is turned into a *normative* annex, which requires **web browsers** to support octal escape sequence for compatibility reasons (non-web-browser hosts can choose to stick to the default implementation).

While previous versions of ECMAScript did address support for octal escape sequence, it was only for Numeric and String literals. Backward-compatible RegExp is describes for the first time in [Section B.1.4 of ES6](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/index.html#sec-regular-expressions-patterns), which changes the semantics and syntax of RegExp for BMP patterns to include support for octal escape sequence, among other features.

### Unmatched closing brackets `]` and non-range-quantifier with `{}`

Another common extension (as tested on Firefox 38, Chrome 43 and IE9) is to relax the grammar to allow unmatched closing brackets `]` and sequences that don't constitute a numbered quantifier and interpret them as literal strings.

```
/^][[]]$/.test("][]"); // Tokens: ^  ]  [[]  ]  $
/^{56, 67}$/.test("{56, 67}"); // Extra space
```

Similar to octal escape sequence, the default grammar of RegExp ([section 15.10.1 of ES5.1](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/index.html#sec-15.10.1), or [section 21.2.1 of ES6](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/index.html#sec-patterns)) doesn't allow `{`, `}`, `]` to be an *Atom*, as those character are excluded from the production of *PatternCharacter*.

The grammar in [Annex B section B.1.4 of ES6](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/index.html#sec-regular-expressions-patterns) is also extended to interpret non-range-quantifier sequences (sequences which don't match the grammar of *QuantifierPrefix*) as literal string, via *Atom[U] :: PatternCharacter* production.

**However**, the extended grammar doesn't allow unmatched closing `]`, as both *PatternCharacter* and *PatternCharacterNoBrace* production still disallow `]`.

Answer (score 9):

Yes, Mozilla's Gecko engine did support the [*sticky* `y` flag](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/sticky), which was not part of ES5. It did eventually became part of ES6.

This ability may be utilised again when engines start implementing [look-behind](https://esdiscuss.org/topic/look-behind-proposal) (I hope they start experimenting before it will get specced).

<sub>This is not an exhaustive list, just what first came to my mind. There may be other examples.</sub>

Comment: I hope they do it with a subclass now that `RegExp` is subclassable.

Comment: "it must not extend the RegularExpressionBody and RegularExpressionFlags productions defined below or the productions used by these productions." - this makes it sound as if their extension was invalid anyway , or am I understanding it wrong?

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum: No, the …Body and …Flags productions just define the form of literals so to say, not the grammar of the regexp and the allowed flags. Any implementation must be able to parse all literals, even if it is extended, and the implementation does not understand the contents of the regexp.

Comment: So it is allowed to extend `new RegExp(pattern, flags)` but not `/pattern/flags`? (`/y` worked on literals too afaik). So `new RegExp(pattern)` and `/pattern/` can behave differently?

Comment: No, `RegularExpressionLiteral` basically allows totally arbitrary characters (and `flags` only must consist of `IdentifierParts`). It's [RegExpInitialize](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-regexpinitialize) that throws on invalid flag characters.